# Case of names for template typename

Tags: c++

Given a C++ template class (or function) definition:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  T member;
};
```

-- if in a more complicated case I want to make the typename more expressive, what case naming conventions are accepted or shunned (and why). Examples:

```
template<typename MORE_EXPRESSIVE_NAME>
struct More {
  MORE_EXPRESSIVE_NAME* p_;
  More(MORE_EXPRESSIVE_NAME* p);
  ...
};

template<typename MORE_EXPRESSIVE_NAME>
More<MORE_EXPRESSIVE_NAME>::More(MORE_EXPRESSIVE_NAME* p)
: p_(p)
{ }
```

*or*

```
template<typename MoreExpressiveName>
struct More {
  MoreExpressiveName* p_;
  More(MoreExpressiveName* p);
  ...
};

template<typename MoreExpressiveName>
More<MORE_EXPRESSIVE_NAME>::More(MoreExpressiveName* p)
: p_(p)
{ }
```

*or*

```
template<typename mr_exprs_nm>
struct More {
  mr_exprs_nm* p_;
  More(mr_exprs_nm* p);
  ...
};

template<typename mr_exprs_nm>
More<mr_exprs_nm>::More(mr_exprs_nm* p)
: p_(p)
{ }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main thing about naming convention is consistency. Whatever the convention you adopt, please keep it throughout the project, and therefore if you jump in on a project where there is already one adopted, stick to it (if there is none, rename).

That being said, ALL caps are normally reserved for macros in most of the naming conventions I have seen, so I would definitely avoid it.

I myself prefer to name template parameters like I name types or constants (depending on the kind of the parameter), for consistency. In this case, given that you use `More` I would use camel case too.

As for the content of what you type, it depends:

- for small functions, I usually use the Concept name, possibly abbreviated: `FwdIt` for `ForwardIterator` for example, as a reminder of what the type should implement
- for larger class / functions, I use either a Concept or a meaningful name (business-dependent) if possible

Comment: I like this set of rules of thumb. However, I'd add to it that, when you adopt a naming convention, then use an existing one. There's already way too many of them out there for C++. Adding yet another one doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

MORE_EXPRESSIVE_NAME looks like precompiler constant. mr_exprs_nm is not much better than Foo. I vote for MoreExpressiveName. There are various naming conventions, but in this case simple common sense helps to find the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

As Matthieu M. says, when it comes to naming conventions, consistency is more important than the convention itself.

That said, here's the convention I use:

`CamelCase` for structs, classes, typedefs & template parameter names.  Basically, anything that looks like the name for a type is CamelCase.

```
template<typename MoreExpressiveName> ...
```

I also use `CamelCase` for `static const` globals

```
static const int MyMagicNumber = 42;
```

`underscore_lcase` for variable & parameter names.  Member variables also get a `trailing_underscrore_`.

```
template<typename MoreExpressiveName> 
More<MoreExpressiveName>::More(MoreExpressiveName* my_thing)
{
  my_thing_ = my_thing;
}
```

`ALL_CAPS` for macros.